# How to configure .zshrc file to have command and path in different lines

Tags: linux, zsh, zshrc

I'm using ZSH and wondering if there's a config I can add to my .zshrc file that can separate the command line and path line.

Before:

```
localhost /workplace/sudo/myservice/src/myservice % [cursor here]
```

Expecting:

```
localhost /workplace/sudo/myservice/src/myservice % 
[cursor here]
```

I know Oh My Zsh can do that but just wondering which exact config was implemented to achieve this?

Comment: I think your solution can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53789/whats-the-newline-symbol-in-zshs-ps1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert a literal line break.

Before:

```
PS1='%m %~ %# '
```

After:

```
PS1='%m %~ %#
 '
```

Done.

Alternatively, you can use a `$''` string, which lets you use `print` escape characters, such as `\n` for newline:

```
PS1=$'%m %~ %#\n '
```